# How to show Angular Material Tooltip on component initialization

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I want to show an Angular Material tooltip when its component is initialized/loaded.

I know I can add an HTML attribute to show it when an event happens. My overall goal is to have the tooltip showing when the component loads, then hide after a few seconds.

I've tried the following:

```
<div (load)="tooltip.show()"
     #tooltip="matTooltip"
     matTooltip="blah blah">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**YoukouleleY** is almost correct, you need to put it into **ngAfterViewInit()** and add **setTimeout()** to make it work:

```
@ViewChild('tooltip') tooltip: MatTooltip;

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.tooltip.show();
   this.cd.detectChanges();
   setTimeout(() => this.tooltip.hide(2000));
}
```

---

Added update with changeDetectorRef to avoid ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. Hope that helps.

Comment: That did solve my problem, however it also throws the error:

`Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'zoom: undefined'. Current value: 'zoom: null'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?`

Comment: @possum_pendulum I've updated answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@ViewChild('tooltip') tooltip: MatToolTip;

ngOnInit() {
  this.tooltip.show();
  this.tooltip.hide(2000);
}
```